# How to delete Source from Org that is deployed accidentally?

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

**Requirement:**
I have installed FFLib ApexMocks Framework(https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks) and FFLib Apex Common(https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common) in my developer edition org.

After installation, I noticed that the components from above frameworks are mixed up with the components I developed

I want to delete those components deployed from above frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution
Tools Needed: Visual Studio Code with SFDX CLI

- Open VS Code SFDX Project
- Connect to org from which you want delete components
- Create an empty package.xml
- Create a destructiveChangesPost.xml with all components mentioned
- Run below command

  ```
   sfdx force:source:deploy –manifest .\manifest\package.xml
  –postdestructivechanges .\manifest\destructiveChangesPost.xml
  ```

**Empty package.xml**

```
<Package `xmlns`="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```

**destructiveChangesPost.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>fflib_Answer</members>
        <members>fflib_AnswerTest</members>
        <members>fflib_AnyOrder</members>
        <members>fflib_AnyOrderTest</members>
        <members>fflib_ApexMocks</members>
        <members>fflib_ApexMocksConfig</members>
        <members>fflib_ApexMocksTest</members>
        <members>fflib_ApexMocksUtils</members>
        <members>fflib_ApexMocksUtilsTest</members>
        <members>fflib_Application</members>
        <members>fflib_ApplicationTest</members>
        <members>fflib_ArgumentCaptor</members>
        <members>fflib_ArgumentCaptorTest</members>
        <members>fflib_IDGenerator</members>
        <members>fflib_IDGeneratorTest</members>
        <members>fflib_IDomain</members>
        <members>fflib_IDomainConstructor</members>
        <members>fflib_IDomainFactory</members>
        <members>fflib_IMatcher</members>
        <members>fflib_IObjects</members>
        <members>fflib_ISObjectDomain</members>
        <members>fflib_ISObjectSelector</members>
        <members>fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork</members>
        <members>fflib_ISObjects</members>
        <members>fflib_ISelectorFactory</members>
        <members>fflib_IServiceFactory</members>
        <members>fflib_IUnitOfWorkFactory</members>
        <members>fflib_InOrder</members>
        <members>fflib_InOrderTest</members>
        <members>fflib_Inheritor</members>
        <members>fflib_InheritorTest</members>
        <members>fflib_InvocationOnMock</members>
        <members>fflib_Match</members>
        <members>fflib_MatchTest</members>
        <members>fflib_MatcherDefinitions</members>
        <members>fflib_MatcherDefinitionsTest</members>
        <members>fflib_MatchersReturnValue</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodArgValues</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodArgValuesTest</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodCountRecorder</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodReturnValue</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodReturnValueRecorder</members>
        <members>fflib_MethodVerifier</members>
        <members>fflib_Mocks</members>
        <members>fflib_MyList</members>
        <members>fflib_Objects</members>
        <members>fflib_ObjectsTest</members>
        <members>fflib_QualifiedMethod</members>
        <members>fflib_QualifiedMethodAndArgValues</members>
        <members>fflib_QualifiedMethodAndArgValuesTest</members>
        <members>fflib_QualifiedMethodTest</members>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactory</members>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactoryTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectDescribe</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectDescribeTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectDomain</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectDomainTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectMocks</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectSelector</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectSelectorTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectUnitOfWorkTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjects</members>
        <members>fflib_SObjectsTest</members>
        <members>fflib_SecurityUtils</members>
        <members>fflib_SecurityUtilsTest</members>
        <members>fflib_StringBuilder</members>
        <members>fflib_StringBuilderTest</members>
        <members>fflib_System</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactory_crossobject_fieldsets_not_allowed_error</members>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactory_fieldset_wrong_sobject_error</members>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactory_recursive_subquery_error</members>
        <members>fflib_QueryFactory_subquery_invalid_relationship</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_field_not_insertable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_field_not_readable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_field_not_updateable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_object_not_deletable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_object_not_insertable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_object_not_readable</members>
        <members>fflib_security_error_object_not_updateable</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```